# Set BroadcastReceiver to be inactive

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver set up in my Android application that receives SMS receive events. This works fine, but I want to be able to toggle SMS receiving on and off by toggling the BroadcastReceiver on and off. Because if I have a simple boolean inside the onReceive method, even if the SMS receiving is off, my application will start.

Is this possible to do?

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int)) to enable/disable a component in your manifest file. You create a `ComponentName` with your package name and class name of your broadcast receiver. Then use the `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED` flag to disable it. And depending on if you want the entire `Application` object to die or not use the `DONT_KILL_APP` flag or 0. Though the documentation warns against not killing the `Application`.